Parted in scripted mode can increase but not decrease partition size
I am trying to use parted in scripted mode to resize a partition.
When I use the command to increase the partition size it works but when I use the same command but simply change the sector size to reduce the partition size it does not work.
If however I enter those details in interactive mode everything works fine whether increasing or decreasing the size of the partition.
I test with a .img file with one partition containing a btrfs file system. I loop mount the .img file to /dev/loop and partition 1 is at /dev/loop0p1. Partition 1 has an end sector at 48878656.
In the tests that follow I never try to increase the size of the partition beyond the maximum space available on the .img "disk" or below the size of the file system the partition contains.
Here I use parted in script mode to give information about the partition:
[flex@thinkpad ncp-pi]$ sudo parted -s -a opt /dev/loop0 "unit s print"
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 120933888s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  48878656s  48876609s  btrfs

I use parted in scripted mode to INCREASE the size of the partition by increasing the position of the end sector from sector 48878656 to sector 49078656 and this works as expected:
[flex@thinkpad ncp-pi]$ sudo parted -s -a opt /dev/loop0 "unit s print resizepart 1 49078656 print"
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 120933888s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  48878656s  48876609s  btrfs

Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 120933888s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  49078656s  49076609s  btrfs

Now using the same command I try to reduce the size of the partition by reducing the position of the end sector from sector 49078656 back to sector 48878656 however this does not work, the script wants me to answer 'Yes/No' even though I am in scripted mode?
[flex@thinkpad ncp-pi]$ sudo parted -s -a opt /dev/loop0 "unit s print resizepart 1 48878656 print"
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 120933888s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  49078656s  49076609s  btrfs

Warning: Shrinking a partition can cause data loss, are you sure you want to continue?
[flex@thinkpad ncp-pi]$

I check the partition size again and nothing has changed, so that last command did not complete:
[flex@thinkpad ncp-pi]$ sudo parted -s -a opt /dev/loop0 "unit s print"
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 120933888s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  49078656s  49076609s  btrfs

If instead I enter those details in interactive mode everything works fine.
There are some other questions on stackoverflow and other sites about parted in scripted mode. Functionality differs a little across distros and there may be a bug in it.
Other questions about parted in scripted mode:

How to use parted in script mode?
GNU parted resizepart in script
no way to use resizepart non-interactively on busy partition (Bug Report)

None of these sites have answered my question. How come my command to use parted in scripted mode can increase the size of the partition but not decrease it? How can I debug or find out what's going wrong?

You might want to use an Expect script, so you can respond to prompts more dynamically.

parted -s is supposed to make parted run so you are not shown any prompts which is what I want. The question is why is it prompting me to say yes/no when it is not supposed to do that. Maybe it's a bug in the parted code.

That question would be better asked at [unix.se].

I see lots of other questions on stackoverflow about using parted in script mode. Would appreciate if I can leave this open for a day or two and if I get nothing I'll close it?

If the question were about the script, rather than how parted works, it would be on-topic here.

If you try to shrink a partition, with Parted running in script-mode, Parted issues the warning but then just exits out. This is because running in script mode by design Parted will not accept user input and it will NOT shrink a partition. Parted could give more informative feedback to the user in this scenario but that is how it is currently coded. I got confirmation from a Parted developer of this.
So in this case the problem was my incorrect understanding about how the Parted command is designed to function and also how to use the Parted command to do what I needed.
I have found several work-arounds, for instance these commands always work to increase and to decrease the size of the partition:
echo -e "resizepart 1 46280703s\nyes\nunit s\nprint\nquit" | sudo parted /dev/loop0 ---pretend-input-tty
sudo sgdisk -d 1 -n 1:2048:46378656 /dev/loop0

